# Get values from array based on textarea word position

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I've a JSON file which has arrays and inside it I have values which has the offset(position) too.
I have the textarea on which I want to get index position of each letter and when user right then check the index position and match it with array offset(position) and show its values over the context menu. This is my JSON API:
[image]

Like I'm getting these all values of array altogther not based on their position inside context-menu.

```
foreach ($json2['matches'] as $key=>$val) {            //json2 has JSON details
  foreach ($val['replacements'] as $new=>$qwe) {       //all replacement values
        echo '<input type="button" value="'.$qwe['value'].'">';    //all values
  }
}
```

This is how my context-menu looks:
[image]

I want to show specific values from JSON based on selected word not altogether. Like to check the API offset number and letter position then show only its values(suggestions).

Comment: As I understand you need something like this : `foreach ($json2['matches'] as $key=>$val) {
 foreach ($val['replacements'] as $new=>$qwe) {
  if(strtolower($qwe['value']) == strtolower('your search string')){
   echo '<input type="button" value="'.$qwe['value'].'">';
  }
 }
}`

Comment: Actually the textarea has the wrong grammar or words but the values of array has the correct words which are basically replaceable. So, the option I see is may be match the offset value with search word position. I tried to do it. But whenever I click on textarea text it shows me its index position number but when I pass it to the foreachloop to check then It get only 0 from that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've developed the whole context-menu and getting specific word suggestions on context-menu. Highlighting the wrong words. Its working now they I wanted it too.